# jquery.hammer.js crashes on android but works fine on ios

Tags: android, jquery, ios, touch, hammer.js

I have built a slide show and right now I am trying to add swipe support that cross platform compatible. currently my jquery hammer js build works great on ios but not in android 4. in android my slide show will run until I try to swipe to another slide, then it stops working. Its a pretty simple setup. I only care about left and right swipe and want the default vertical scroll.

```
var hammertime = $('#slideshow').hammer();
    hammertime.on("swipeleft", function(ev) {
    ev.gesture.preventDefault();
    swipeLeft();
});
hammertime.on("swiperight", function(ev) {
    ev.gesture.preventDefault();
    swipeRight();
});
```

slide will work perfectly in ios without the preventDefault() function, I put it in for android as it has given some success for android in the past, but this time yielded no extra results. Any ideas on whats causing android not to work at all here?

Comment: Android 4.x phone, hammer.js's swipe touch hardly work. small percent of swipe action is accepted as event. why?... Browser issue or hammer.js's problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this.
I found that hammer.js recoginze most of swipe touch as drag.

```
var hammertime = $('#slideshow').hammer();
    hammertime.on("swipeleft dragleft", function(ev) {
    ev.gesture.preventDefault();
    swipeLeft();
});
hammertime.on("swiperight dragright", function(ev) {
    ev.gesture.preventDefault();
    swipeRight();
});
```